# Ordering Datatable using Linq Or without creating copy of DataTable

Tags: c#, .net, linq, .net-4.0, datatable

I have the below code using System.Data.DataSetExtensions:

```
var orderedTable = myDataTable.AsEnumerable().OrderBy(x=>x["ID"].ToString())
myDataTable = orderedTable.CopyToDataTable();
```

Is this the easiest way to order the original datatable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Further to Stanley's ans you can do

```
 DataView dataView = new DataView(myDataTable);
      dataView.Sort = "ID";
     DataTable d = dataView.ToTable();
```

Answer (score 4):

Use a DataView:

```
DataView dataView = new DataView(myDataTable);
dataView.Sort = "ID";
```

Note that it does not sort the actual DataTable, but gives you a view on top of it that is sorted.

Answer (score 1):

Creating a new object or changing the data type seems unnecessarily...

you can use Datatable.[DefaultView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.defaultview.aspx).Sort

for example:
`myDataTable.DefaultView.Sort = "ID";`